# Convert Unicode text to characters which were typed on keyboard

Tags: unicode

I want to know how to Convert Unicode text to characters which were typed on the keyboard.
Like if I typed 'bsm' in URDU keyboard then 'بسم' is written. so i want to convert بسم to 'bsm'.

Actually, I have a whole paragraph and I want to know how to convert it back to the characters which typed it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You also need to tag the question with the (programming) language you're using; without that, it's likely to be closed as "too broad".

Comment: Actually there is no code. I'm asking for any way this can be achieved ; by using any software or any code snippet. I'm good at C++ and PHP so if any class or library can be used to achieve this in either of languages. It would be helpful